# Using Saha's equation knowing the overall pressure

Tags: star, mathematics, hydrogen, gas

Knowing the pressure, $P_g$, how can I calculate $\frac{N_{I+1}}{N_I}$ using Saha's equation?

If I assume that $P_g=(n_e+n_{H^+}+n_H)K_B T$ and that $n_e=n_{H^+}$, I can find the electronic pressure, $P_e$, and plug it in Saha's equation, but then I'm left with $n_H K_B T$, which is gonna screw my calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The pressure of a gas depends on the number density of particles and the temperature. There is therefore no unique relationship between $P_g$ and $N_{I+1}/N_I$.

Comment: Let's assume I also know the temperature. Is it possible then?